# How to determine if an object is an inherited from a certain class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In the test:

```
if(v is BaseModel)
```

will assert true if v is a direct instance of type BaseModel but will 
assert false if v is not a direct instance of type BaseModel but is inherited from BaseModel. Would it be nice if Kotlin has a keyword that will assert true if there is a keyword 'is from' such that the test

```
if(v is from BaseModel)
```

will assert true if v's class is inherited from BaseModel.

But how do Kotlin resolve this currently?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The code you posted does *precisely* what you're asking

Comment: Just got confused, no need for 'is from' key word is' is also capable of doing that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Krzysztof Kozmic said, the example you gave does exactly what you're asking for. Just to give some more examples:

```
// Built in types
val x: Int = 25
println(x is Number) // true

// Custom types
open class A
open class B : A()
open class C : B()

println(B() is A) // true
println(C() is A) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing what you're asking is how to determine if `v` *directly* inherits `BaseModel` as opposed to via an intermediate base class?

If that's the case, then this will do:

```
v.javaClass.superclass == BaseModel::class.java
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, you are to be able to check inherited classes like this example.

```
open class A {}

class B : A() {}

class C {}

class M {
    fun call() {
        A()::class.isInstance(B()) //true
        A()::class.isInstance(C()) //false
    }
}
```

Please be careful about the turn of input classes in lines that have a comment.